# Changing Maki icon color in mapbox?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to add color to Mapbox's maki icons in plain Javascript. There's documentation for using the deprecated tilemill tool, and there's a method of using CSS to color them. However, my icons are being generated dynamically from an array of objects with Lat/Lon coordinates, and I want to have them be colored dynamically based on some other data inside said object (I'm trying to have a transit station icon sized and colored based upon the amount of daily traffic it receives). Unfortunately, the default mapbox icons have color control but pretty weak sizing support, with only three strings (large, medium, small) to determine size.

The code I have is here:

```
featureArray = []

// stationData is an array of objects
stationData.forEach(function(station) {

            var markerObj = {
                type: 'Feature',
                properties: {
                    title: station.StationName,
                    "icon": {
                        "iconUrl": "public/maki/renders/marker-24@2x.png",
                        "iconSize": [40, 40],
                        "icon-fill": "#DF0101",
                        "popupAnchor": [0, -15],
                        "className": "dot",
                        "iconColor": '#fa0' // does not work
                    }
                },

                geometry: {
                    type: 'Point',
                    coordinates: [parseFloat(station.Lng), parseFloat(station.Lat)]
                }
            }

            featureArray.push(markerObj);
        });

        var geojson = {
            type: 'FeatureCollection',
            features: featureArray
        };

        stationLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
            var marker = e.layer,
            feature = marker.feature;

            marker.setIcon(L.icon(feature.properties.icon));
        });

        stationLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);

        stationLayer.on('mouseover', function(e) {
            e.layer.openPopup();
        });

        stationLayer.on('mouseout', function(e) {
            e.layer.closePopup();
        });
```

I've been googling for a few hours and trying different methods with no luck.

Thanks,

William

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unfortunately, the default mapbox icons have color control but pretty weak sizing support, with only three strings (large, medium, small) to determine size.

You'll need to use Mapbox.js and `L.mapbox.markerLayer` or [`L.mapbox.marker.icon`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.8/l-mapbox-marker-icon/). Sizes beyond large, medium, small (and the retina versions of those) would be scaled in-browser and blurry, and using the maki download won't be re-colorable, since our markers API re-colors icons on the fly using server-side code with [node-blend](https://github.com/mapbox/node-blend).